# INVALID_TABLE_PROPERTY: For input string: "0-23" (property: projection.hour.digits) on Athena

Tags: aws-glue, database-partitioning, amazon-athena

Having error while running this query

**Query on Athena**

```
SELECT * FROM "db"."thermostat" 
where id='95686' 
and "date" = '2022/03/07'
AND hour =13
```

**Projection Partition**

Data located on this path:
`s3://bucket/dbname/tablename/id/date=2022/03/07/hour=13/`

**Error**

> INVALID_TABLE_PROPERTY: For input string: "0-23" (property: projection.hour.digits) (table
> db.thermostat)

**Table Properties**

```
 'projection.enabled' = 'true',
  'projection.id.type' = 'injected', 
  'projection.date.format' = 'yyyy/MM/dd', 
  'projection.date.interval' = '1', 
  'projection.date.interval.unit' = 'DAYS', 
  'projection.date.range' = '2019/11/27, NOW-1DAYS', 
  'projection.date.type' = 'date', 
  'projection.hour.type' = 'integer',
  'projection.hour.range' = '0-23',
  'projection.hour.digits' = '2',
```

Comment: Are you setting the storage.location.template setting on the projected table?

Comment: @Golammott yes, I set storage.location.template setting on the projected table.  this error got resolved but now query returning zero record. 

``` SELECT * FROM "db"."thermostat" 
where id='95686' 
and "date" = '2022/03/08'
and hour =06```

Comment: @Golammott could u tell me what wrong with query?

Comment: data location 

s3://thermostat-bucket/db/thermostat/id=95686/date=2022/03/08/hour=06/

Comment: It's got resolved as well. Thanks @Golammott for ur time.

Answer (score 3):

I had written range
`'projection.hour.range' = '0-23'`

But it should have like this
`'projection.hour.range' = '0,23'`